# Getting UITextField value in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

It's my first question here so please bear with me, (I was searching for days but I can’t find any answer! T.T) I am also a newbie on IOS development, so sorry if I get the terms wrong, I need to get the value of `UITextField` in my app. I am using `UIPageViewController` and 2 View Controllers:

The first View Controller is the root view using `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`, and this is where my `UIPageViewController` declared. 
The second view is the pages view, inside this view is there are 2 UITextFields. 
So in my app, I have 2 pages both using the second view controller.

My first problem is, I was not able to get the `UITextFields`’ value using the root view class, but then I found a way to do that by declaring `UIPageViewController` in the .m of my `rootviewcontroller` interface, so I think I solved it my own way.

However, I am getting this values by clicking a button before turning to next page, Is there anyway I could get the `UITextField` value when I turn to next page without clicking the button? 
Next is, when I turn to next page and go back to the first page, when I click the button it is not getting the `UITextField` value anymore.

So, I was able to get `UITextField` value by identifying the placeholder on the first `UITextField` of every page.

I have the `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods, but their behavior is weird.. the calling of this method at my app is inaccurate when I turn my page back and forth for many times sometimes one of this method is not called.

Also, I used this site http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/  as my guide on creating this.

Hope somebody could help me… Thanks!

Comment: You can store values of required text filed globally, I mean in a singleton class or on your `AppDelegate`. You can access the `AppDelegate` instance  globally like this - 

`MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: I'll try that, however, my main problem is identifying the pages.. since the viewControllerBeforeViewController and viewControllerAfterViewController are inaaccurately called, I have no way to distinguish which is the first page and second page. I want to distuingish both so when the page is turned back and forth the datas in the uitextfield are readable by the button or when the page is turned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPageViewController` has the `viewControllers` property. You can access it to get an array of the `UIViewController`s. Using this, you will be able to get the access the `SecondViewController`s.

`pageViewController.viewControllers[1]` will give you the instance of the first `SecondViewController`. Just make sure to declare the `textField` globally in the `SecondViewController` and you can access it to retrieve the text entered.

Also, Paddy's answer should work as well. Have two different keys for the two `textField`s  and access them separately.

Comment: This is exactly what I need!! However, I have two pages... but when I tried to NSLog the array of viewcontrollers in my UIPageViewController, there is only one... do you know why? and could you also give me some tip on how to  add another view controller in my UIPageViewController so they would have separate viewcontroller for each set of uitextfield?thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sadly I still can't upvote so I just accepted your answer :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *NSUserDefaults* to hold the value of your TextField.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("TextField value", forKey: "nameKey")
```

and to get the value

```
let name = defaults.stringForKey("nameKey")
```

Once you save the value, you can use this in the whole project.

Comment: I could do that, thanks for the reply! but is there anyway I could automatically store the uitextfield value without clicking the button? instead just when the page is turned?

Comment: After a gesture-driven transition completes this delegate method is called:

pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:

Comment: If the page turn completed it will return YES. So you can store the value.

Comment: I did that what you said... and the problem is... the value it stores is the value from the second page not from the first page... I need the value of texfield from the first page as well, any other way? :( Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: What i mean is, at first completed transition using NSLog to identify the value I am getting... the value from the first page is empty even though I inputed something, at the second page I tried inputing a value a the textfield and after the second transition that's when it stores the value but from the second page not from the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! I got it all solved by myself and the help of these people above! Thanks for the advise guys! you were such a great help to me!!! What I did is just I made two viewcontroller for the pages so I don't need my UItextfield to be sharing two inputs! Thanks!!!